# How to handle Money data type when writing to Parquet

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, parquet

I've been trying to get data from sql server, load to dataframe, and write to parquet (which later I loaded to BigQuery or other source).
I've got some problem with money data type, for example when the data in sql server:

> 100,000

but after writing to parquet it converts to:

> 100

(because the data size is big, I can't download to my local to make sure, but maybe `write.parquet` change money to int, please correct me).

Here's part of my script:

```
df = spark.read.format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", "jdbc:sqlserver://{myIP}:1433;instanceName={myInstance};database={myDB};") \
    .option("dbtable", table_source) \
    .option("user", user_source) \
    .option("password", password_source) \
    .option("driver", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver") \
    .load()

df.write.parquet("gs://output/sample.parquet")
```

Should I specify a scheme for each column? or are there some better approaches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is because the `,` character is being treated as a decimal point. Can you confirm the data type in SQL server is numeric?

If the type in SQL server is numeric, then you can try manually removing the `,` and casting to double or string before writing to parquet. If its not numeric then you will have to do the casting anyways.

Comment: True, it's treated comma (,) as decimal point (.), the only thing to make data consistent is casting to string type, but I can't do some calculation like SUM or AVG with this data type. 

Casting to double or float made some 0 behind the comma missing like 100,0000 become 100, but the one thing I miss is how you replace the comma (,)?
I'm use regexp_replace to replace (,) but I belive the output is same, but when I try to replace decimal point (.) like this:
```df2 = df.withColumn('data', regexp_replace('data', '.', '-'))```
the output in dataframe column become: ------ (without number)

Comment: this is because second argument in `regexp_replace` is `"."` which is considered as a regex and means match all. so lits replacing all characters with the substitution character `"-"`. you have to use `val df2 = df.withColumn('data', regexp_replace("data", ",", "."))`

Comment: thanks for your help, now I know why it replaces all the data, already mark your answer as accepted but sorry my rep isn't enough to +1 your question, I hope somebody with the same problem found it and give that +1 or I'll give +1 later if I've got 15 rep